# The class 'Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity\Message' was not found in the chain configured namespaces My\DemoBundle\Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have below doctrine configuration,

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default    
        connections:

            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                   enum:    string

            em1:                    
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   em1
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8

            em2:                    
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   em2
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: default

    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
              MyDemoBundle : ~
              MyMessagingBundle : ~
        em1:
            connection: em1
            mappings:
              MyOtherBundle : ~
        porting:
            connection: em2
            mappings:
              SonataNotificationBundle: ~
              ApplicationSonataNotificationBundle: ~
```

I have all my entities in MyDemoBundle

using entities of MyDemoBundle,  MyMessagingBundle  is reading tables from em1 database, creating messages to send email and passing those messages to sonata backend service which should store them to sonata's table 'notifications__message' in database em2.  But I am getting error

The class 'Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity\Message' was not found in the chain configured namespaces My\DemoBundle\Entity

Looks like calling service of SonataNotificationBundle which is under em2 entity manager  from MyMessagingBundle which is under em1 enitiy manager does not allow sonata to access its entities under em2. It tries to find entities from where the service is called.

Initially when  below bundles where under em1 everything was working fine. I just move them to em2 entitiy manager.

SonataNotificationBundle: ~
ApplicationSonataNotificationBundle: ~

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself got the solution,

I just digged in to SonataNotificationBundle code.

They have,

```
<services>
    <service id="sonata.notification.entity_manager" alias="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" />

    <service id="sonata.notification.manager.message.default" class="Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity\MessageManager">
        <argument type="service" id="sonata.notification.entity_manager" />
        <argument>%sonata.notification.message.class%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

Hardly coupled default entity manager so moving SonataNotificationBundle under custom entity manager won't work.

To fix it, I created service in config.yml with same name, and passed custom entity manager to it.

```
services:
    sonata.notification.entity_manager:
        alias: doctrine.orm.em2_entity_manager
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a better way to do this using your `app/config/config.yml`

```
sonata_notification:
    class:
            message: MyDemoBundle\Entity\Message
```